# Recursively calling a second function inside a function

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code that counts up -3, -2, -1. I have also written another that counts down 3, 2, 1. If the condition is true for another after an input, the program should stop. For Example, The input i enter -3 for negatives it gives -3, -2, -1, if i enter positive number like 3, the result should be 3, 2, 1 in a single combined code.

I have tried to put a function into an if statement of the first function but fails with "NameError: name 'countdown' is not defined" for count down but count up works.

```
print('+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+ F1')
#count up
def countup(n):
        if (n >= 0):
                print('Hello')
                if n==0:
                        print('Blastoff!')
                else:
                        print(n)
                        countdown(n-1)
        else:
                print(n)
                nth = n + 1
                countup(nth)
result = int(input('Enter Number: '))
countup(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the second `else` with `elif`? And fixing the indenting? The resulting code should be this:

```
print('+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+ F1')
#count up
def countup(n):
        if (n >= 0):
                print('Hello')
                if n==0:
                        print('Blastoff!')
                elif (condition): 
                        print(n)
                        countdown(n-1)
               else:
                    print(n)
                    nth = n + 1
               countup(nth)
result = int(input('Enter Number: '))
countup(result)
```

Comment: That's weird. What version of python are you using? And can you give the full error?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by doing this code below:

```
def countup(n):
    if (n >= 0):
        print('Blastoff 1')
    else:
        print(n)
        nth = n + 1
        return countup(nth);

def zero(n):
    if (n==0):
        print('You have erntered 0 program exiting')
        exit()

def countdown(n):
   if (n <= 0):
      print('explode 2')
   else:
      print(n)
      nth = n - 1
      return (countdown(nth))

num = int(input("Enter number: "));
if (num <= 0):
    print(countup(num))
elif num == 0:
    print(zero(num))
else:
    print(countdown(num))
```

The output is either negative or positive, regardless of what integer you fuse in